# Is it possible that my xampp server makes videos on my website lag?

Tags: html, performance, video, server, xampp

I have a XAMPP server set up on my computer with the following specs:

GeForce RTX 3070
AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor
16 GB RAM (15.95 GB RAM usable)

On the server I am running a website with a couple of short videos that acts as animations. The videos run perfectly smooth during the first 15 minutes of restarting the server but they eventually start to get really choppy.

I have followed many guides on how to optimize video performance, I have switched to webm, and the websites network payload is less than 10mb, I have followed all the recommendations that Lighthouse gave me and have a 100 performance score but the videos are still really choppy.

Should I maybe consider switching to a cloud based video hosting service? The videos is currently in a HTML video tag with the videofile directly linked inside the tag.

Any help would be appreciated .